# Is it possible to get the url from a link clicked in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, hyperlink

Is it possible to get the url from a link clicked in an iframe using jquery or similar? I don't have any control of the iframe.

Comment: need more info...till now yes it is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that "I don't have any control of the iframe" means "The page in the frame is on a different origin and CORS is not granting permission to me" then no. The [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) forbids it.

Comment: Is it possible in some other way? like on hover or something like that?

Comment: @user1052055 — No. You cannot get any data out of the remote site.

Comment: Ok thanks for your replies, one last shot though. Is it possible to force links that are clicked in the iframe to open in a new window?

Comment: No. To do that you would have to be able to get references to the links out of the frame.